# Why does running "go test" only run tests in my main_test.go file?

Tags: go

At the root of my project, I have a `main.go` and a `main_test.go` file. I have another test file `query_test.go` that is in a nested folder and that doesn't get run. How do I make `go test` run all files that end with `_test`?

Answer (score 6):

To run all tests you just do:

```
go test ./...
```